# Dynamically updating and getting data in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

so I've been messing around with Mongo lately using [Mongoose](http://%20https://mongoosejs.com/) and I came to a bump lately. I want to update and get something but without specifically targeting it. Let me explain myself better.

I have this schema:

```
id: {
    required: true,
    type: String
},
information: {
    number: String,
    Identification: String,
    title: String,
    address: String
},
products: {

}
```

Now ofcourse I won't hardcode every product into the schema because there are a lot of products..etc, what I eventually want to do is to update `doc.updateOne({'products.productIDHere.review': newReviewData}, { new: true, upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true })`
So whenever a client changes their review or rating..etc it will update that.
Here are my questions:

1- How do I insert the products individually without overwriting everything within `products:{}`.

2- How do I update the review or rating value within a certain product.

3- How do I get information about that product because I cannot do something like `doc.products.product.id.review`, product.id is the only information I have about the product.

4- Do I need to change something about the schema?

Please try to answer with Mongoose as some answers are different in MongoDB than how their executed in Mongoose. No problem if you rather answer in MongoDB sense though.

Comment: I know you are looking for a Mongoose-oriented answer but could you help us with an example document before-and-after for these questions?   Esp. the updates.

Comment: Sure @BuzzMoschetti, a document would look something like this:
        id: "1234567890",
        information: {
            number: "1234567890",
            Identification: "Something",
            title: "Mr.",
            address: "St.Something"
        },
        products: {
            "1234567890": {
                review: "Such a great product",
                rating: 4,
                name: "TV"
            },
            "23456789": {
                review: "Broke too soon",
                rating: 3,
                name: "Fridge"
            }
        }

Comment: I see you are using keys as product IDs, e.g. `products.1234567890.review`.   That is an antipattern in MongoDB.   I strongly recommend you change this to an array of named items e.g.  `products: [ {name: "1234567890", review:"A"}, {name: "23456789", review: "B"} ]`  Is it possible to change?

Comment: Could be changed yes, how will I add new documents, get documents and update documents if I do so?

Comment: OK!  Change possible.   Also:  Do you want only 1 review per product or multiple?  Most designs like this capture an ever growing list of datestamped reviews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a time-honored data design: products and reviews.  A good, simple, scalable way to approach it is with *two* collections: product and reviews.  The product collection contains all details about a product and carries the product ID (pid):

```
{pid: "ABC123", name: "TV", manu: "Sony", ...}
{pid: "G765", name: "Fridge", manu: "Whirlpool", ...}
```

The reviews collection is an ever-growing list of pid, timestamp, and review information.

```
{pid: "G765", ts: ISODate("2020-03-04), author: "A1", review: "Great", rating: 4}
{pid: "G765", ts: ISODate("2020-03-05), author: "A2", review: "Good", rating: 3}
{pid: "G765", ts: ISODate("2020-03-06), author: "A3", review: "Awesome", rating: 5}
```

If you're thinking this sounds very relational, that's because it is and it is a good design pattern.
It answers the OP questions easily:
1- How do I insert the products individually without overwriting everything within products:{}.  **ANSWER:**  You simply add a new product doc with a new `pid` to the product collection.

2- How do I update the review or rating value within a certain product.  **ANSWER**  Not sure you want to do that; you probably want to accumulate reviews over time.  But since each review is a separate doc (with a separate `_id`) you can easily do this:

```
db.reviews.update({_id:targetID},{$set: {review:"new text"}});
```

3- How do I get information about that product because I cannot do something like doc.products.product.id.review, product.id is the only information I have about the product.
Easy:

```
db.product.find({pid:"ABC123"})
or
db.product.find({name:"TV"})
```

Comment: @QZAK  Don't be shy about hitting up arrow for +1 on an accepted answer.